# Plotting best fit line with ggplot for regression in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

For the dataset below, I would like to run an additive regression model, regressing withdraw on estress and affect. Then, I need to plot the predictions (fitted line) on the sample, with affect on X axis. The mean of estress can be used as a constant value for the best fit line.

My current code looks like this:

```
model.add <- lm(withdraw ~ estress + affect, data = estress.dat) 

library(ggplot2)
estress.dat$addFit <- predict(model.add, newdata = estress.dat)
ggplot(estress.dat, aes(x = affect, y = estress, color = withdraw)) + 
  geom_point() +
geom_line(aes(y = addFit), size = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

However, the plot I get looks incredibly weird, with jagged lines. So I think I'm probably doing it wrong. Any help to correct my code would be appreciated!
[image]

Sample of my data:

```
structure(list(tenure = c(1.67, 0.58, 0.58, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2.5, 
0.5, 0.58), estress = c(6, 5, 5.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 5.5, 3, 5.5, 6), 
    affect = c(2.6, 1, 2.4, 1.16, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.16, 1.33, 3), 
    withdraw = c(3, 1, 3.66, 4.66, 4.33, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4), sex = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
    "male"), class = "factor"), age = c(51L, 45L, 42L, 50L, 48L, 
    48L, 51L, 47L, 40L, 43L), ese = c(5.33, 6.05, 5.26, 4.35, 
    4.86, 5.05, 3.66, 6.13, 5.26, 4), addFit = c(2.98571051159875, 
    1.83195137430683, 2.87030819668908, 2.10870572064622, 1.87037481064259, 
    2.13966887974888, 1.79352793797107, 2.10870572064622, 2.04734042752603, 
    3.29336201408961)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your regression is of `withdraw` (the fill value) against `affect` (x-axis) and `estress` (y-axis).  So `addfit` will be a predicted `withdraw` value, not a predicted `estress` value.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! would you have any feedback on how to improve my code to fix this? sorry I am very new to this all and a bit lost

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. From your description, it sounds as if you might want to plot predicted withdraw against affect, where the prediction uses estress = mean(estress)??? It is probably straightforward once you are clear about what you are trying to do.